# WPF Usercontrol based on Textbox/Popup definition

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, user-controls, popup

I created a "UserControl" based on a TextBox. That means I created a new UserControl and replaced UserControl by TextBox in xaml and xaml.cs files.

Now I want that my new TextBox control shall have a popup to display some suggestions.

Now my question is: Where can I define the look/structure of the Popup as XAML? The Popup definition shall be part of the newTextBox.

That's what I have:

```
    <TextBox x:Class="WpfApplication11.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication11"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         MaxWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth}">
    </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're totally missing what a `UserControl` actually is. To put it simply, a `UserControl` is a **group** or **collection** of controls that make up one larger... uh... control.

> I want that my new TextBox control shall have a popup to display some suggestions.

What you are describing here **is** a `UserControl`. You cannot place a `Popup` inside a `TextBox`.

So. What you're after here is probably something like this:

```
<UserControl ... >
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="txt" 
                 Width="150" ... />

        <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=txt}"
               Placement="Bottom"
               IsOpen="True"
               StaysOpen="True"
               Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=txt}">
            <!-- Some popup content here -->
        </Popup>

     </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is obviously an extremely simplified example, but you get the idea.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Could you show me how to bind the Popup width to the width of the TextBox? Making them both the same width.